# ReferenceError: Worker is not defined in simple Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, web-worker

I'm creating an incredibly simple Firefox extension. I used `cfx init` to create the directory structure and have code in `lib/main.js` and `data/my_worker.js`

`main.js` is as follows:

```
var worker = new Worker("my_worker.js");

worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};

worker.postMessage("Bobby");
```

and `my_worker.js` is as follows:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    self.postMessage("Hello " + e.data);
};
```

Then I run: `cfx run` to run the extension. The results are as follows:

> (addon-sdk-1.17)me:lib me$ cfx run Using binary at
>   '/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin'. Using profile
>   at
>   '/var/folders/p1/zzdzcrrx6pq96hgsmy5xjqmh0000gp/T/tmp57OYe9.mozrunner'.
>   console.error: test:    Message: **ReferenceError: Worker is not defined**
>   Stack:
>       @resource://jid1-zmowxggdley0aa-at-jetpack/test/lib/main.js:1:9 CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:129:18
>   run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:138:19
>   startup/

I tried putting `my_worker.js` in both the `data` and `lib` folders but neither works. This seems like a SUPER simple extension. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a good idea to read [some intro docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials) before starting to code.

The Firefox add-on SDK [uses modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Module_structure_of_the_SDK) that need to be imported into `main.js` using the `require` function. There is no global `Worker` object, as the error is pretty explicit about. A content script needs to be attached to an HTML page somewhere; it can't exist alone. The three most common ways to get a worker are by attaching a content script to

[a tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#attach(options))

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
      contentScript:
        'document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";'
  });
});
```

any page that matches an array of URLs or regex, using a [`PageMod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Communicating_With_Content_Scripts)

```
var tag = "p";
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("element-getter.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.emit("getElements", tag);
    worker.port.on("gotElement", function(elementContent) {
      console.log(elementContent);
    });
  }
});
```

an invisible background page with [`PageWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker), which is probably what you're going for

```
pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
  contentScript: "console.log(document.body.innerHTML);",
  contentURL: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet"
});
```

Note that [`panel`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel) work very similarly to `worker`s in that they have `onMessage` and `port` attributes.

Note also that `onMessage` is spelt with a capital `M`

Comment: Awesome, great answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox Addon, use **ChromeWorker** instead of worker.

Add the following lines in **main.js**

```
var { ChromeWorker } = require("chrome");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var data = self.data;

var localWorker = new ChromeWorker(data.url("my_worker.js"));

worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};

worker.postMessage("Bobby");
```

**my_worker.js**

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    self.postMessage("Hello " + e.data);
};
```

put your **my_worker.js** file in **data/** directory.

Comment: any idea how to get the webworker importScripts function working for chrome workers?