# JS Files not included in the Package created through CFX tool

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox Add-On through CFX tool but while i am using cfx.xpi the Addon xpi is not having other Javascripts files which i am using as a thread ( using Worker ).
I am using :
var twrite = new Worker("t_write.js");

t_write.js is my worker file. But while executing it like this it is giving an Error: Malformed script URI:t_write.js

Please help me by letting me know how to include those files in the add-on package and what is this Malformed Scipt Error

Comment: This is the second time someone has come here with code using `new Worker()`. What have you read that makes you think there is a `Worker` constructor function? Please see my other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048624/referenceerror-worker-is-not-defined-in-simple-firefox-extension/27050057#27050057)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.Worker
 I have gone through this document . I have used                 const {Worker} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm"); for importing Worker . It is creating a worker object but it is not calling the postMessage or onmessage functions either. Please tell me the solution

Comment: That is a web API that is not accessible from a backend script. No [web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) are accessible from a backend script. My other answer shows how to create a worker in the addon context, which is simply used to communicate with a page. If you want to use a *web* worker to do threading, see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27108935/1720014)